# questions about icon property in openlayers 3

Tags: icons, openlayers-3

I have a question about icon property including anchor, anchor Origin, offset, offset Origin. because the open layers web didn't give more explanation and it confuses me, when i change anchor or offset, they both can change icon position, and offset and size both can cut the icon, and what does Origin mean, those properties confuse me for a long time. 
Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**anchor**: specifies where the "tip" point of the icon is. To use mouse pointers as an analogy, standard arrow has its anchor on the top-left corner, a cross has the active part exactly in the middle, etc. OpenLayers allows you to specify that via a vector between [0,0] and [1,1] (e.g. [0.5, 0.5] is in the middle, etc.).

**anchorOrigin**: which part of the icon should the `anchor` be applied from. Default is top-left, meaning that the top-left corner would be used as a point of reference if **anchor** is to be applied. I'd say that it's probably best to ignore it and go with the default, only modifying **anchor**.

**offset**: if you only want to use a part of your input image as the icon (because, for instance, there's some unnecessary margin), you can shift the active area by [x, y] pixels

**offsetOrigin**: which point of the icon should be used as the point of reference for the **offset** property.

Note that if you use `offset` then it makes sense to have a look at `size`.

Comment: very good explanation, thanks Kryger, I got it with the instance you explained